# Openssl output to socket

Tags: shell, openssl, socket, node.js

I want to extract the signer from an S/MIME file inside a node app. I use `(child_process.spawn()`, which runs this command

```
 openssl smime -verify -CAfile c_root.pem -inform DER -signer /proc/self/fd/1
```

It doesn't work because the input and the output are sockets (not pipes).  The same command works if the output is a pipe.

stderr:

```
Verification successful                                                                                                                                       
Error writing signers to /proc/self/fd/1
40C71EA94D7F0000:error:80000006:system library:BIO_new_file:No such device or address:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(/proc/self/fd/1, w)
40C71EA94D7F0000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75:
```

How to do this operation without temporary file?

Comment: If you have `openssl | something` then openssl's /proc/self/fd/1 is a pipe (and works) not a socket. I can't believe you're actually doing what you say.

Comment: `|` is for semantic. actualy i do `child_process.spawn()` funstion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround is wrap in `/bin/sh` and pipe to `cat`.

```
sh -c "openssl smime -verify -CAfile c_root.pem -inform DER -signer /proc/self/fd/1 | cat"
```